# Main 4 inch waste pipe broken

Tags: walls

I'm a renter and have had a horrible egg smell under  crawl space. Waste has is been going on in my house for three months all he did was fix pipe with PFC and put lye down I've been sick dog and wife is. Am I in danger  I feel yes and what r my rights

Comment: If your staying in the house you should at least have fans blowing in and out of the crawl space. Box fans work good.

Comment: then send your landlord an email or registered letter saying you want the dirt removed for under the house in the affected areas. Then a plastic vapor barrier laid on the ground and up the sides of the foundation.

Comment: You should be contacting a doctor and lawyer, not a DIY website.  Rotten egg smell is typically natural gas, though I guess could be sewage.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about medical and or legal issues.

Answer (score 1):

**Let me preface this with a disclaimer; I am not a lawyer nor a health professional.**

That said, the smell is likely hydrogen sulfide which in high enough concentrations can kill you, but since the problem is fixed it probably isn't nearly strong enough for that; most likely you'd just experience respiratory irritation. I recommend trying to keep it aired out as much as possible, so the gas doesn't build up. You should contact your landlord and get them to address the issue.

As far as your rights, that is entirely dependent on your location. **If your landlord won't address the issue, this is probably the point where you should get your local health department involved**; in most jurisdictions they can force property owners to address issues that are public health concerns.